# Why Am I Getting NaN?

Tags: c#

I'm going through my code and each time D1 ends up being NaN.  The code looks fine to me, and I'm completely stumped...

```
double D1;
Data Data = new Data();

PriceSpot = 40;
Data.PriceStrike = 40;
Data.RateInterest = .03;
Data.Volatility = .3;
Data.ExpriationDays = 300;

D1 = 
    (
        Math.Log(PriceSpot/Data.PriceStrike) +
        (
            (Data.RateInterest + (Math.Pow(Data.Volatility,2)/2)) *
            (Data.ExpirationDays/365)
        )
    ) /
    (
        Data.Volatility *
        Math.Pow(Data.ExpirationDays/365,.5)
    );
```

Comment: Considering you have both ExpirationDays and ExpriationDays in your code, I'd say this is not your actual code. Can you post the actual code instead? Also, can you post the definition of the Data struct/class so we can see the types of those fields/properties?

Comment: Exact same mistake as you made here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344994/progress-bar-only-appears-after-work-is-complete/3345141#3345141

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Data.Volatility * Math.Pow(Data.ExpirationDays/365,.5)` is 0 since 300/365 as int equals to 0

Assuming `ExpriationDays` property is of type `int` indeed, it'll make the whole expression be 0.

For example:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var val = 300 / 365;

    Assert.That(val, Is.EqualTo(0));
}
```

*Some comment about dividing by 0:*

When dividing two 0 integers an exception will be thrown at runtime:

```
[Test]
public void TestIntDiv()
{
    int zero = 0;
    int val;

    Assert.Throws<DivideByZeroException>(() => val = 0 / zero);
}
```

When dividing two 0 doubles the result will be NaN and no exception will be thrown:

```
[Test]
public void TestDoubleDiv()
{
    double zero = 0;
    double val = 0 / zero;

    Assert.That(val, Is.NaN);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb.  Ok, thanks. 
And I thought I was doing the right thing by using int for ExpirationDays rather than double. 

Thanks

Comment: You can keep it at int if you want, but note that int/int is an integer division, however int/double is a floating point division, so you can just tuck on .0 on 365 to make it work the way you want it, ie. `Data.ExpirationDays/365.0`

Comment: Lasse, that is an excellent suggestion and something I was not aware of.  I will implement what you are suggesting.

Comment: You can also cast the value to double.

Answer (score 3):

Check the type of `Data.ExpirationDays`, it may be that `Data.ExpirationDays/365` is evaluating as 0 if the type is integral. That would mean the denominator would be zero (the square root of zero is zero and zero multiplied by Data.Volatility is *still* zero) which would lead to a problem.

In fact the numerator turns out to be zero in your case as well since log<sub>n</sub>1 is always zero and you're adding that to zero (another value which is multiplied by `Data.ExpirationDays/365`).

You may want to consider using floating point types throughout the process.

Comment: but wouldn't that throw an exception, instead of returning NaN?

Comment: That would depend - IEEE754 has signalling (as in exception) and non-signalling (as in return an NaN) NaNs. I don't know off the top of my head which C# uses or whether it's configurable.

Comment: You're not performing `n / 0`, you're performing `0 / 0`. Your logarithm is resulting in 0, and you're adding the same `ExpirationDays / 365` to it.

Answer (score 1):

- `Data.ExpirationDays/365` is equal to zero.
- 0 ^ 0.5 is equal to zero too.
- Data.Volatility * 0 = 0.
- D1 = Something / 0.

So NaN is quite expected.

Comment: You're assuming ExpirationDays is an int (or other integer type). It's a safe assumption though since that will produce the NaN, but it *is* an assumption nonetheless.

Comment: You're right. Looking at the code, I assumed `ExpirationDays` is an integer because of `Data.ExpriationDays = 300;` (and I always write `double A = ... ; A = 300.0` in my own code). But of course, since it is a class property, it can be `double ExpirationDays [...] = 300`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you've mis-spelled Data.ExpirationDays as Data.ExpriationDays so Data.ExpirationDays is defaulted to 0?  This would give 0/0 ie NaN (numerator is 0 b/c you happen to have strike=spot)

( I've never used C# so am not sure whether this is only an error in your posting or in your code (which I would have expected the compiler to catch) )

Comment: That would only work if he has both fields/properties in his type, ie. both the one with the correct spelling and the one without. I find that unlikely (but not impossible) so I doubt that is it.